# Git - Different Remote for each Branch

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, git-merge

I'm unsure of how to ask this properly but I'll try and do my best - I'm by no means a Git aficionado, I know *how* to use the basic commands but not advanced terminology/functionality.

I have a private repository `myrepo` cloned from a private server `git.mydomain.com`. I'm familiar with the process of branching code on the same repository with `git checkout -b mybranch` - however I'd like to branch to GitHub rather than my private server, resulting in something like this:

```
Repo       Branch      Remote Location    (Purpose)
------------------------------------------------------------
myrepo --> private --> git.mydomain.com  (Incremental work)
  |
  +------> public  --> github.com        (Public releases)
```

Essentially I'd like to be able to `git checkout public` and `git merge private`.

Comment: Would it fit your workflow to just push that branch to a different origin (Github) when you are ready?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can set a different branch to push to a different server for individual branches by using these commands:

**As of Git 1.8.0:**

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/foo foo
```

Note: If the last `foo` is left out, it will choose the current branch.

**As of Git 1.7.0:**

```
git branch --set-upstream foo origin/foo
```

In your case, you would use this by adding your two remotes (`mydomain` and `github`) and setting each branch to push to them individually. It might look something like this:

Make sure you add the remotes if you haven't already:

```
git remote add github git://github.com/foo/myrepo.git
git remote add mydomain git://git.mydomain.com/foo/myrepo.git
```

Then set the branches to push to the right places:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to mydomain/private private
git branch --set-upstream-to github/public public
```

After this is all set up, you can push and pull just by using `git push` and `git pull`. This will push and pull to the `github` remote when you're on the public branch, and to your `mydomain.com` remote when you're on your private branch.

Comment: In this same scenario, is it possible to tell git to selectively add files to the public branch? For example if I have folders dist, src and README.md in private and I want only dist and README.md to appear in github i.e. the public repo, how can I go about achieving this?

Comment: @SaifurRahmanMohsin The branch will have the same files no matter which server it's pushed to. If you want to have specific files on a specific branch, then commit only those files to that branch.

Answer (score 2):

First of all add your remotes like

```
git remote add remote1 https://github.com/username/repo1.git
git remote add remote2 https://github.com/username/repo2.git
```

Note: `remote1` and `remote2` are replacement of `origin`

**For those who get error** while following [Jonathan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569146/jonathan-wren) above answer like me

> error: the requested upstream branch 'remote1/b1' does not exist

The command `git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote-name>/<branch-name>` expects the remote branch to exist locally or already be fetched from the remote repository.

If the remote branch `b1` at `remote1` (https://github.com/username/repo1.git) doesn't exist locally, you need to fetch it first.

You can follow these steps to set the upstream branch for `b1` and push it to `remote1`:

Fetch the remote branches from `remote1`:

```
git fetch remote1
```

Create a local branch `b1` that tracks the remote branch `b1`:

```
git checkout -b b1 remote1/b1
```

Set the upstream branch for `b1` to `remote1/b1`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=remote1/b1
```

Push `b1` to `remote1`:

```
git push remote1 b1
```

These steps ensure that you have the remote branch `b1` locally, set it as the upstream branch, and push it to `remote1`.

Similarly you can repeat it for `remote2` as `https://github.com/username/repo2.git` for branch 2 `b2`