# Git: push to different locations per branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'd like to set up a git repository in which I can push/pull my changes to/from different locations depending on which branch I am.
The idea is to have two branches:

- master: for internal development (I'm disallowed to publish it at all) I
  would push/pull from local Stash
- dev: for pulling changes from github and contribute back, and also use it to merge
  changes occasionally to the master

I assume that with this setup I can easily handle internal/public development on the same project.
Now I'm stuck at how to do this. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775362) answer but it seems to me
that remote locations can be applied only on a whole repository rather than for separate branches.

How do fix this? If this is not the way to go, please suggest me a best practice.

Comment: [The git config docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) have settings for exactly this kind of thing.  Look for the `branch.` and `remote.` items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Different Remote for each Branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775183/git-different-remote-for-each-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long format of `git push` is:

```
git push remotename localbranch:remotebranch
```

It gives you all the flexibility needed to selectively push branches to desired remotes.

Examples

1. Push `master` branch to `origin`

   ```
   git push origin master
   ```
2. Push `develop` branch to `myfork`

   ```
   git push myfork develop
   ```
3. Push `develop` branch to a branch called `newbranch` on `myfork`

   ```
   git push myfork develop:newbranch
   ```
4. The full syntax with colon can also be used to delete a branch. This deletes `newbranch` from `myfork` by pushing "nothing" into it

   ```
   git push myfork :newbranch
   ```

I tend to mostly use explicit commands with git rather than relying on some default behavior. Whenever a collegue is stuck on git there's usually a plain `git pull` or `git push` in his command history which makes me smile (or sigh if I'm in a particularly bad mood).

Since you're also asking for tip, before pushing you might want to look around:

```
git remote -v
git fetch remotename
git branch -a
```